# PostgreSQL upgrade issue $libdir/postgis-1.5 $libdir/plr

Tags: postgresql, osx-mountain-lion, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to upgrade from PostgreSQL 9.1 to PostgreSQL 9.2 on Mac OS X using binaries provided by William Kingesbury and for hours haven't been able to isolate a critical issue with the loadable libraries.

Firstly I got the following error:

```
Could not load library "$libdir/postgis-1.5"
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory

Could not load library "$libdir/plr"
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plr": No such file or directory
```

and eventually found out that these extensions were stored in the `/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/lib/` directory.

I checked all of my databases in 9.1 but none of them actually use these extensions with `\dx+` in the psql terminal window.

How can I get rid of the references to these libraries from my old 9.1 database? I deleted them manually from the extension folder (`*.plr` files) and from the `/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/lib/`, but during the upgrade I still get the same error mentioned above.

I also tried to copy the library files named `plr.so` and `postgis-1.5.so` to the new `/usr/local/pgsql-9.2/lib/` directory, however this had no noticeable effect on the outcome apart from giving me the following error:

```
Could not load library "$libdir/postgis-1.5"
ERROR: incompatible library "/usr/local/pgsql-9.2/lib/postgis-1.5.so": version mismatch
DETAIL: Server is version 9.2, library is version 9.1.
```

I could presumably figure out how to install PostGIS-1.5 under PostgreSQL 9.2, but isn't there a way to remove it from the old installation?

Answer (score 1):

> I could presumably figure out how to install postgis-1.5 under postgresql9.2

That would be the right thing to do.

> but there should be a way to remove it from the old installation?

Well, you could deactivate 9.2, reactivate (and launch) 9.1, amend your data as needed, re-dump the data, deactivate 9.1, reactivate and launch 9.2, and reimport the data...

You might also manage by manually editing your db dump to remove the references.

But in the end, it'll probably be easier and shorter to just install postgis-1.5 for 9.2.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - the problem has been solved with help from William Kyngesbury and Denis - thanks heaps!

There is an uninstall file (`.sql`) for old PostGIS versions, which is located in the following directory by default:

```
pgsql-9.1/share/contrib/postgis-2.0/uninstall_legacy.sql
```

As Denis previously suggested, I have also reactivated my 9.1 instance of PostgreSQL:

```
sudo ln -sfh pgsql-9.1 /usr/local/pgsql
```

For the next step, I ran the `uninstall_legacy.sql` script in each of my databases. In fact, in only one of the databases several functions were removed and since I did not know how to remove PL/R, but at the same time was suspicious that I created the extension in this database, I dropped the whole database after an SQL dump.
Then I reactivated my PostgreSQL 9.2 instance again and launched it.

Now the pg_upgrade process ran without errors and PostgreSQL and PostGIS are both running smoothly once again.